# How to remove this part of the URL?

Tags: html, wordpress, web, url, hyperlink

I have a problem that I hope you can help me with. So, basically, I developed a portfolio website for a client, and it has 4 sections: home, work, feed, info.

So the thing is that I developed everything but the home page using Wordpress (Semplice template, which is kind of a live editor).The home page was created using html, css and js on my own.

I uploaded everything to my host, and I want the website to load firstly the Home page I designed with my code. From this home page you can go using the nav to the other sections created with Wordpress.

So one of the main things that I already solved was the fact that I had in the same folder an index.php (the wordpress default index, needed to load all of the other wordpress sections, so I cant delete it) and the index.html (the one I've coded myself). As I couldn't just delete the index.php as it was necessary to load the other wordpress sections, I had to use the .htaccess file to redirect it, so when I type https://mysitedomain.com it goes to https://mysitedomain.com/index.html

I managed to do it pasting this code on top of the .htaccess file:

```
RewriteRule ^$ https://mysitedomain.com/index.html [L,R=301]
```

What I want to do now is hiding that "/index.html" from the main link when I go to the website. If I take it away from my .htaccess file, the website will charge the wordpress index.php, which is what I am trying to avoid.

#### **How can I hide that "/index.html" from the main link but not affecting the redirection that I previously did to charge my index.html file instead of the wordpress index.php?**

Answer (score 0):

5 steps:

- create a new page template: `my_index.php`

Add PHP comment at top of file:

```
 /*
    Template Name: My Index
 */
```

- copy / paste index.html into `my_index.php`
- create new page, set template to `My Index`
- set new page as homepage.
- delete or rename index.html

Answer (score 0):

Add to top of .htaccess file the following line and remove your index.html RewriteRule:

```
DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
```